# Using sed to grab filename from full path?

Tags: sed

I'm new to sed, and need to grab just the filename from the output of `find`. I need to have find output the whole path for another part of my script, but I want to just print the filename without the path.  I also need to match **starting from the beginning** of the line, not from the end.  In english, I want to match, the first group of characters ending with ".txt" not containing a "/".  Here's my attempt that doesn't work:

```
ryan@fizz:~$ find /home/ryan/Desktop/test/ -type f -name \*.txt
/home/ryan/Desktop/test/two.txt
/home/ryan/Desktop/test/one.txt
ryan@fizz:~$ find /home/ryan/Desktop/test/ -type f -name \*.txt | sed s:^.*/[^*.txt]::g
esktop/test/two.txt
ne.txt
```

Here's the output I want:

```
two.txt
one.txt
```

Ok, so the solutions offered answered my original question, but I guess I asked it wrong.  I don't want to kill the rest of the line past the file suffix i'm searching for.
So, to be more clear, if the following:

```
bash$ new_mp3s=\`find mp3Dir -type f -name \*.mp3\` && cp -rfv $new_mp3s dest
 `/mp3Dir/one.mp3' -> `/dest/one.mp3'
 `/mp3Dir/two.mp3' -> `/dest/two.mp3'
```

What I want is:

```
bash$ new_mp3s=\`find mp3Dir -type f -name \*.mp3\` && cp -rfv $new_mp3s dest | sed ???
 `one.mp3' -> `/dest'
 `two.mp3' -> `/dest'
```

Sorry for the confusion.  My original question just covered the first part of what I'm trying to do.

2nd edit:
here's what I've come up with:

```
DEST=/tmp && cp -rfv `find /mp3Dir -type f -name \*.mp3` $DEST | sed -e 's:[^\`].*/::' -e "s:$: -> $DEST:"
```

This isn't quite what I want though.  Instead of setting the destination directory as a shell variable, I would like to change the first `sed` operation so it only changes the `cp` output before the "->" on each line, so that I still have the 2nd part of the `cp` output to operate on with another '-e'.

3rd edit:
I haven't figured this out using only sed regex's yet, but the following does the job using Perl:

```
cp -rfv `find /mp3Dir -type f -name \*.mp3` /tmp | perl -pe "s:.*/(.*.mp3).*\`(.*/).*.mp3\'$:\$1 -> \$2:"
```

I'd like to do it in sed though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
find yourdir -type f -name \*.txt | sed 's/.*\///'
```

or, slightly clearer,

```
find yourdir -type f -name \*.txt | sed 's:.*/::'
```

Answer (score 17):

Why don't you use basename instead?

```
find /mydir | xargs -I{} basename {}
```

Comment: And its friend, dirname. Would be great if you showed a working example that uses the details provided in the question.

Comment: i'd never heard of basename, and I'm glad i know about it now, but I was hoping for some sed regex help.

Answer (score 10):

No need external tools if using GNU find

```
find /path -name "*.txt" -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: How did I not know about this?!? This is an incredibly handy feature to know. Thank you! Isolate directories with `find /path -name "*.txt" -printf "%h\n"`

Answer (score 4):

I landed on the question based on the title: using sed to grab filename from fullpath.
So, using sed, the following is what worked for me...

```sh
FILENAME=$(echo $FULLPATH | sed -n 's/^\(.*\/\)*\(.*\)/\2/p')
```

The first group captures any directories from the path. This is discarded.

The second group capture is the text following the last slash (`/`). This is returned.

Examples:

```sh
echo "/test/file.txt" | sed -n 's/^\(.*\/\)*\(.*\)/\2/p'
file.txt

echo "/test/asd/asd/entrypoint.sh" | sed -n 's/^\(.*\/\)*\(.*\)/\2/p'
entrypoint.sh

echo "/test/asd/asd/default.json" | sed -n 's/^\(.*\/\)*\(.*\)/\2/p'
default.json
```

Comment: I too landed based on the title and this answer helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
find /mydir | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    path="parentdir2/parentdir1/parentdir0/dir/FileName"
    name=${path##/*}
```